# Real examples of Communities based on new Lightning templates: Koa, Kokua, Napili?

Tags: community, community-builder

Community Builder is already in place for some time - as well as new Lightning-enabled templates: Koa, Kokua, Napili.

Do you maybe know some real example (publicly available) of communities based on those templates? I wonder how much they are customized. Or in other words: to which extend those pre-configured templates comply to real business usecases.

BR

Jacek Bialecki

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce claims there are over 900 active lightning communities, check these dreamforce videos to know about the use-cases and success stories  -

https://www.salesforce.com/video/302765/, 
https://www.salesforce.com/video/183627/

As for the real life examples, I came across the [Logitech community](https://community.logitech.com/s/) that is built on the Napili template, you can self-register to get an inside peek into the customization aspect.

Home depot community appears to be built on Napili template, check this [out](http://community.homedepot.com/)